# RSpec HTTP Request - How to set Port number

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra, httprequest

Is there a way to set the port number for a request (GET in this scenario) in a RSpec test?

I currently have this which uses the port that a Sinatra application runs on:

```
  it "invalid GET PORT" do
    get '/'
    expect(last_response).not_to be_ok
  end
```

I want to be able to test port 1234 for example something like this

```
get ':1234/'
```

What is the proper syntax?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You would usually want to set the port number in the describe block, but it should work in the it block as well.

```
it "invalid GET PORT", port: 1234 do
```

Comment: This gives me a syntax error. So does using it in it block. I also tried                                                          `it "invalid GET PORT", port: 1234 do`  (no comma after port number) and there was no syntax error but test fails

Comment: My mistake just updated my answer. I added an extra comma. It should work now.

Comment: Thanks JoelL. Unfortunately, this does not seem to work. The `get '/'` still seems to use the application port as the test returns an ok response.